# How to add image in a documents in DocuSign

Tags: docusignapi

Am trying to add image in my docusign documents via Curl.

I think i have to use  **signerAttachment** parameter.

Assuming my image is  http://sample.com/myphoto.png. Where do I add it as per code below.  Or what is the best solution to achieve that

```
"signerAttachmentTabs": [
                {
                  "name": "sample string 1",
                  "tabLabel": "sample string 2",
                  "scaleValue": 1.1,
                  "optional": "sample string 3",
                  "documentId": "sample string 4",
                  "recipientId": "sample string 5",
                  "pageNumber": "sample string 6",
                  "xPosition": "sample string 7",
                  "yPosition": "sample string 8",
                  "anchorString": "sample string 9",
                  "anchorXOffset": "sample string 10",
                  "anchorYOffset": "sample string 11",
                  "anchorUnits": "sample string 12",
                  "anchorIgnoreIfNotPresent": "sample string 13",
                  "anchorCaseSensitive": "sample string 14",
                  "anchorMatchWholeWord": "sample string 15",
                  "anchorHorizontalAlignment": "sample string 16",
                  "tabId": "sample string 17",
                  "templateLocked": "sample string 18",
                  "templateRequired": "sample string 19",
                  "conditionalParentLabel": "sample string 20",
                  "conditionalParentValue": "sample string 21",
                  "customTabId": "sample string 22",
                  "mergeField": {},
                  "tooltip": "sample string 23",
                  "tabOrder": "sample string 24",
                  "tabGroupLabels": [
                    "sample string 1"
                  ]
                }
              ],
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, you can add an image just like you add any other document, be it a PDF or HTML or anything. The image will be in its own page, not embedded in some other doc.

Looking at the image you posted, you may be trying to embed this inside an existing document, and that cannot be done using attachments.

You could use a special type of tab called [drawing tab](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ldoKjdY0DD4), which allows for embedding drawings, graphics, images etc. inside a document.
Right now the content of the drawing tab cannot be set via the API

Comment: Drawing tabs' contents cannot be set via the API.